# In my wordpress dashboard showing an error meassage when i tried to update plugins

Tags: wordpress, apache, server, capacity, downtime

My website showing an error message when I tried to update plugins. Error message is

> Update Failed:  503
>   Service Unavailable Service Unavailable The server is temporarily
>   unable to service your request due to maintenance downtime or capacity
>   problems. Please try again later. Apache Server at "website name"

Comment: did you tried *later*?

Comment: I tried again showing error message. [Link : http://www.wordpresstechy.com ]

Comment: What kind of hosting do you have? Can you access a static page like yourdomain.com/readme.html

Comment: Yes i can access. [http://www.wordpresstechy.com/readme.html]

Comment: @Anupa does your problem occurs at linked website or you need to me your question there?

Comment: When i tried to upload image to media also showing same error message

Comment: Please answer these: 

1) What kind of hosting do you have?  cPanel or something else?
2) Is the drive full?  
3) Can you FTP to your server.?

Thanks

Comment: Godaddy server. Drive not full

Answer (score 0):

503 Service Unavailable is a server error. Your website is not retrieving data from the server itself. Therefore whatever you update on your website will take no effect. You need to contact Godaddy for support. You might need to upgrade your plan or increase your bandwidth limit. Their support team can advice you properly.